# Data format sent from Device to android app via Bluetooth Low energy

Tags: android, c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to run a BLE example code of Texas instruments send and receive some parameters from my device to android app. I am able to send the data from my device to Android/ios BLE app. Now my questions are,
1) In what format (JSON/XML) the data is sent from device to android?. I am aware it should be mentioned in the program.
2) Since i am trying to send the health parameters like heart rate, Blood Pressure etc. should i follow the IEEE format compulsorily to send the data?. The IEEE data specifications link is given below.
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/Health-Device-Profile

Please help me out, i am relatively new to Bluetooth technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not about how TI BLE device sends the data but how Android BLE API presents it to the developers or vice versa. Think about it like a black box or a layered system. TI BLE device communicates with the Android mobile phone. Android OS receives the data and presents it to the developer. When you receive data from TI BLE device, the Android app callback `onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)` is called. Then you must call `characteristic.getValue()` which returns in the data type of `byte[]`. You don't have to worry about how data is transferred in the air. It is the job of lower layers. Use TI BLE SDK and Android BLE SDK. Read the manuals and don't worry about the lower layer tasks. There are simple functions to do the fundemental BLE events. The SDKs are for developers to simplify their jobs.
2. It is up to you. If you want your TI BLE device to communicate with any Android application which implements BLE Heart Rate profile, then you should follow the specs in the link you typed. If the app is just specific to your needs and your TI BLE device communicates with your own app then you don't need to follow the specs. In your case, since TI Android Application implements Heart Rate Profile according to specs, you should follow the specs when you implement the profile in your TI BLE device.

Comment: Than you!! You have explained it very well!!